# Objeto JSON vacio desde fetch en Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, fetch, backend

No entiendo por qué me llega un objeto vacío a mi servidor en node.js.
Desde el frontend, puedo comprobar que el objeto tiene datos.

Este es el código de la funcion de mi frontend.

```
function guardarMision(mision){
console.log('entrando en guardar mision');
console.log(mision);
fetch('/guardarMision', {
    method : 'POST',
    body : JSON.stringify(mision),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).then((response)=>{
    misiones +=1;
})
```

}

En el navegador puedo ver que esa estructura misión contiene los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el backend el request me llega vacío. No entiendo por qué.
Este es el código de la función en node.js que se llama desde el fetch.

```
const guardarMision = (req, resp, next)=>{
try{
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.body);
}catch(error){
    imprimirError(error, req, 'Error al validar la cookie en guardar mision');
    resp.sendStatus(500);
}
resp.sendStatus(200);
```

}

Adjunto captura parcial del request con el body vacío, y el console.log(req.body) que se ve abajo como {}.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podéis echar una mano?

Comment: Si tienes instalado algun middleware para parsear el body? si pones `console.log(JSON.stringify(mision))` si obtienes lo que deseas enviar al body?

Comment: Tal como te comentan, en el backend seguramente hace falta una forma de analizar el cuerpo de la solicitud. ¿Qué tecnología utilizas en el lado *backend*?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el comentario. Como comentaba, esa funciono se ejecuta en el frontend, o sea en el navegador de los usuarios. Un console.log(JSON.stringify(mision)), produce el resultado esperado: {"tipo":"observacion","tropas":["1RZApfgCJPH426au4lYI"],"coordenadasSalida":[38.81690734819659,-1.7757790576105825]}

Comment: El backend se menciona en el titulo. Es nodejs. Utilizo: app.use(express.json());

Comment: No sólo basta con mostrar por consola lo que hay en la variable del lado del navegador, revisa el apartado "network"  y verifica que efectivamente el cuerpo de la solicitud se ha enviado. Si es así, el problema es del lado backend y no del frontend. Dices que usas `express.json`, hay que ver si lo usas en el lugar adecuado. Saludos

Comment: El post del network es exactamente igual al console.log(JSON.stringify(mision)). El problema esta relacionado con los headers.